# call javascript function inside rails hidden_field_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, braintree

I'm setting up Braintree in a simple site. Braintree is a payment plataform. In their examples they use a hiddel_field_tag as follows:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :tr_data, Braintree::TransparentRedirect.transaction_data(
  :redirect_url => confirm_payment_url,
  :transaction => {:type => "sale", :amount => @amount }
) %>
```

now, in my case I want to set the amount of the transaction via a javascript function because I have only three options, and not via the server. I've tried many things, like

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :tr_data, Braintree::TransparentRedirect.transaction_data(
  :redirect_url => confirm_payment_url,
  :transaction => {:type => "sale", :amount => "return amountFunction();" }
) %>
```

where

```
function amountFunction()
{
  var amount = $('input[name=optionsRadios]:radio:checked').val();
  return amount;
}
```

but is not working. I'm still in the learning phase with rails, as you can see. So the questions is, how do I change a variable or add a function to a hidden_field_tag? I could also make :amount => "variable-set-by-javascript", but have not been able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I work at Braintree. We missed this question, but hopefully you contacted [support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/support) or figured out your problem.</sub>

The `Braintree::TransparentRedirect.transaction_data` method runs on the server before the form is rendered, so it needs an actual amount rather than a string that will later be evaluated and return an amount.

In addition, you generally can't / shouldn't set the amount client side / outside the `transaction_data`. That would allow someone to change the amount in the browser and submit a transaction for whatever amount they wanted -- something you want to avoid, as it could cost you money.

Since you posted this question, we've launched [Braintree.js](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/javascript/encryption/overview) which would allow you to post the entire form to your server, and verify the amount is valid there [before submitting the form to Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/getting_paid). I'd recommend using that integration method for any new integrations, or upgrading to it if you need to make other changes to your payment flow.